# In batch, cannot read "*" correctly from file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to analyse a .h file using batch script. In the .h file there are some structs maybe look like this:

```
typedef struct _sample {
    int *a;
    char* b;
    float * c;
} Sample;
```

As you can see, "*" could be anywhere between datatype and member name. Below it is what I wrote in my .bat file(simplified):

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%i in (sample.h) do (
    for %%j in (%%i) do echo %%j
)
```

What this .bat do is echo every word it read since I have simplified it. The result is:

```
typedef
struct
_sample
{
int         ::"*a" is skipped
b           ::"char*" is skipped
float
sample.bat  ::"*" is solved as reading current path files
sample.h
c
}
Sample
```

So the **question** is: How can I analyse this 3 types of pointer declaration with "*" correctly?

Comment: The plain `for` loop uses `*` (and also `?`) as wildcards, so if any of the items after the `in` keyword contains such, `for` accesses the file system and searches for matching items, which are then returned in case; if no wildcards are used, the file system is not accessed and the items are directly returned by `for`...

Comment: It would be a large step from cmd scripting, but if you really want to analyze code, ANTLR would be a good choice. There is great support for C language syntax. http://www.antlr.org/

Answer (score 1):

as aschipfl said, `for` interprets `*` and `?` as wildcards and expands them to matching filenames. To get around it, you must interpret the strings outside the `for` loop:

```
@echo off
for /F "delims=" %%i in (t.txt) do call :doit %%i
goto :eof

:doit
if "%1"=="" goto :eof
echo %1
shift
goto :doit
```

Comment: It's a good first shot, but it's error prone for c-code with arbitrary texts, like `if ( val & 1) printf("val&1 is true");`

Answer (score 0):

If you try to parse C code, you should use a more stable version.
As FOR/F will drop empty lines and lines beginning with `;`.

Also the splitting of the line itself can be done with newlines in a safe way.

```
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
(set \n=^
%=EMPTY=%
)
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%L in (`findstr /n "^" t2.txt`) do (
    set "line=%%L"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "line=!line:*:=!"
    echo LINE: !line!
    FOR %%N in ("!\n!") do set "parts= !line: =%%~N !"
    FOR /F "delims=" %%p in ("!parts!") do (
        echo(   %%p
    )
    endlocal
)
```

Answer (score -1):

As per the `for /?` output:

> ```
> tokens=x,y,m-n  - specifies which tokens from each line are to
>                   be passed to the for body for each iteration.
>                   This will cause additional variable names to
>                   be allocated.  The m-n form is a range,
> ```

note this part:

> ```
>                   specifying the mth through the nth tokens.  If
>                   the last character in the tokens= string is an
>                   asterisk, then an additional variable is
>                   allocated and receives the remaining text on
>                   the line after the last token parsed.
> ```

Comment: This does not answer the question! the real problem is the plain `for` loop which consumes the `*` (and also `?`) as wildcards...